# How to send list value in a single mail in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a list in which there are 2 values. I want to send mail with that list value but every time it is sending a separate mail for each value.

List is:-

```
file_list = ['D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\\Book1.csv', 'D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\\Book2.csv']
```

Sample code:-

```
                 for names in file_list:
                    body = "Hi Team, \n\n NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution script failed due to some reason. " \
                            "\n Please check the attached log file.\n Empty Files :- \n %s" %names  + \
                            "\n\n Thanks & Regards, \n NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution Team"
                    emailstr = "echo '{0}' | /bin/mail -a {1} -s '{2}' '{3}'".format(body, msg_tran, sub, receiver)
                    os.system(emailstr)
```

Output:-

I want a single mail with the name of both the value of the list.
like this:-

```
Hi Team, 

 NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution script failed due to some reason. 
 Please check the attached log file.
 Empty Files :- 
 D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\\Book1.csv
 D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query\\Book2.csv

 Thanks & Regards, 
 NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution Team
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to build your body with loop, not looping on the entire mail construction and sending process

Something like this :

```
body = "Hi Team, \n\n NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution script failed due to some reason. " \
                            "\n Please check the attached log file.\n Empty Files :- \n %s"
for names in file_list:
       body += %names  
body += "\n\n Thanks & Regards, \n NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution Team"
emailstr = "echo '{0}' | /bin/mail -a {1} -s '{2}' '{3}'".format(body, msg_tran, sub, receiver)
os.system(emailstr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping on file_names. 
If you want to send all file_names in one go, then stop looping on file_names
**file_names = " \n ".join(file_list)**

```
file_names = " \n ".join(file_list)

body = "Text %s Text" %names 
body = "Hi Team, \n\n NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution script failed due to some reason. " \
                            "\n Please check the attached log file.\n Empty Files :- \n %s" %file_names  + \
                            "\n\n Thanks & Regards, \n NS_Dashboard_FieldExecution Team"

emailstr = "echo '{0}' | /bin/mail -a {1} -s '{2}' '{3}'".format(body, msg_tran, sub, receiver)
                    os.system(emailstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then looping for each file, you can also convert the list into a string, use

```
% '\n'.join(file_list)
```

in place of `% names` and skip the loop.